# Parse Set variables output to template - Azure yml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline that runs a template pipeline. It looks like this:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repoName
    type: git
    name: projectName/repoName
    ref: branchName

stages:
  - stage: GetLastCommitId
    jobs:
    - job: lastCommitId
      steps:
      - checkout: repoName
      - bash: |
            cd repoName
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=commitId;isOutput=true]$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
        name: a
      - bash: |
            echo $(a.commitId)
      - checkout: self
  - template: templates/bicep.yml
    parameters:
      environment: dev
      lastCommitId: $[stageDependencies.GetLastCommitId.lastCommitId.outputs['a.commitId']]
```

bash returns me the required ID. Everything as it is meant to be.

Now I want to pass this output value to the template as parameter - lastCommitId.

Is there a way to do this?

Here's what I tried:

```
  - template: templates/bicep.yml
    parameters:
      environment: dev
      lastCommitId: $(a.commitId)

Error: Empty string
```

```
  - template: templates/bicep.yml
    dependsOn: GetLastCommitId
    parameters:
      environment: dev
      lastCommitId: $[stageDependencies.GetLastCommitId.lastCommitId.outputs['a.commitId']]

Error: Can not start pipeline. dependsOn not expected here
```

```
  - template: templates/bicep.yml
    parameters:
      environment: dev
      dependsOn: GetLastCommitId
      lastCommitId: $[stageDependencies.GetLastCommitId.lastCommitId.outputs['a.commitId']]

Error: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".GetLastCommitId.lastCommitId.outputs['a.commitId']
syntax according to microsoft doc: $[stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['MyOutputVar.myStageVal']]
```

Here is documentation from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the parameter your are trying to set is done before the actually run of the [tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax). Hence, the lastCommitId is not set as the value and is resulting in your different approaches into a dissapointed result.

But, depending on what is in your bicep.yml, there is a solution!

[image: result]

With the `azure-pipeline.yml` and `bicep.yml` below, you are able to use your lastCommitId in the template:

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repoName
    type: git
    name: projectName/repoName
    ref: branchName

stages:
- stage: GetLastCommitId
  jobs:
  - job: lastCommitId
    steps:
     - checkout: repoName
     - bash: |
           cd repoName
           echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=commitId;isOutput=true]$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
       name: a
     - bash: |
           echo $(a.commitId)
     - checkout: self

- template: templates/bicep.yml
```

And the `bicep.yml`:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: Template
  jobs:
  - job: JobInTemplate
    variables:
      lastCommitId: $[stageDependencies.GetLastCommitId.lastCommitId.outputs['a.commitId']]
    steps:
    - script: echo the value is $(lastCommitId)
```